# To publish Unity default AR Project with React Unity WebGL has a different serialization error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, unity-webgl

#### Development Environment

**Macbook M1 Pro (With Apple Silicon Chip)**
**Unity 2021.3.10f1 (Be compatible with Apple Silicon Chip)**
**Test with Chrome Browser**

#### Current Progress

1. I just create a new project with AR template
2. The project's hierarchy is like below picture.

[image]

3. That building Setting is like below picture.

[image]

4. After building, I get 4 files named **build.data, build.framework.js, build.loader.js, build.wasm**
5. With a **create-react-app** command, I created a new react project. (npx create-react-app ar_tutorial_4 --template typescript)
6. I located those 4 build files under the react's build directory. Like below image.

[image]

7. I edited **index.html** file like this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>React Unity webGL</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

8. And, I edited **App.tsx** file and **index.tsx** file like this.

```js
// App.tsx
import { useRef } from "react";
import { Unity, useUnityContext } from "react-unity-webgl";

function UnityTest() {
  const {
    unityProvider,
    isLoaded,
    loadingProgression,
  } = useUnityContext({
    codeUrl: '/build/build.wasm',
    dataUrl: '/build/build.data',
    frameworkUrl: '/build/build.framework.js',
    loaderUrl: '/build/build.loader.js',
    webglContextAttributes: {
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true,
    },
  });

  const loadingPercentage = Math.round(loadingProgression * 100);
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      {isLoaded === false && (
        <div className="loading-overlay">
          <p>Loading... ({loadingPercentage}%)</p>
        </div>
      )}
      <Unity
        className="unity"
        unityProvider={unityProvider}
        style={{ border: "1px solid red", height: 400, width: 500 }}
        devicePixelRatio={window.devicePixelRatio}
        ref={canvasRef}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export { UnityTest };
```

```js
// index.tsx
import React, { createElement } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { UnityTest } from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(createElement(UnityTest));
```

#### Problem

The screen was normally disappeared but the unity container did not played well.
And, this console error message was displayed.

```
build.framework.js:1771 A scripted object (script unknown or not yet loaded) has a different serialization layout when loading. (Read 52 bytes but expected 76 bytes)
Did you #ifdef UNITY_EDITOR a section of your serialized properties in any of your scripts?
```

#### Question

What should I do to resolve this problem??

Comment: `Did you #ifdef UNITY_EDITOR a section of your serialized properties in any of your scripts?` ... did you? It is also possible that some package/asset you are using did this ... this is just a warning not an error though and shouldn't affect the app much ... this is not really WebGL related but can appear in any target platform

Comment: @derHugo Um... well... i just created a new project with AR template, so there is no scripts written by me

Comment: Then it is scripts written by someone else ;) still this is a warning, not an error, not WebGL specific and shouldn't affect your app at all